# UPDATE Command Parameters in C# For Access 2003 Not update

Tags: c#, ms-access

access 2003
vs 2010 c#

I cannot see where I have gone wrong. There is no error but no data is being updated. I have the insert, delete and edit working but I don't know why I can't get this to work. Please can someone kindly help me here, thanks in advance...

connection string

```
 myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
 Source=C:..\TempDB.mdb");
```

Update method...

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Family] SET [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [FamilyDOB] = ?, [Medical] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?";
        //tried this as well
        //cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Family] SET [FirstName] = FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [DOB] = @StudentDOB, [Medical] = @Medical WHERE [ID] = @ID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtFamID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamDOB", txtFamDOB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medical", txtMedical.Text);

        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supply the parameter values in the same order as they appear in the SQL statement.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamDOB", txtFamDOB.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medical", txtMedical.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtFamID.Text);
```

OleDB plus MS Access doesn't care about the parameter names, only their order.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't aware that sql statement for update required to be in same order, Most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters.

Change this:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtFamID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamDOB", txtFamDOB.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medical", txtMedical.Text);
```

to:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtFamID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtFamDOB.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtMedical.Text);
```

More: [OleDbParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx)

Comment: Completely forgot that, @Iswanto Sam.  I have voted to delete my answer, and +1 to yours.

Comment: @Iswanto - can you claify what should be done at cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE....thanks

Comment: @bucketblast: just use your current code, use `?` for the parameter

Comment: @Iswanto - either of them made any difference?

Comment: @bucketblast: Are you sure the `ID` that you use for UPDATE is exists in the table?

Comment: As HansUp pointed out if I placed txtFamID.Text last then it would have worked.